# Character error when saving PDF to TIFF file using IBM WAS 9 running in RHEL

Tags: websphere, pdfbox, rhel, icafe

Why is checkbox is not rendering properly when saving from PDF to TIFF file. In my local machine (Windows OS) it is working properly but in IBM WAS 9 running in RHEL it does not work. I am using TIFFTweaker ([iCafe](https://github.com/dragon66/icafe)) in combining images to TIFF file and PDFRenderer (PdfBox 2.0.8) in rendering PDF images. Below are the sample codes:

Rendering Images:

```
public BufferedImage renderImage(
        PDDocument document, int index, int dpi, ImageType imageType) 
                throws Exception {
    PDFRenderer renderer = new PDFRenderer(document);

    return renderer.renderImageWithDPI(index, dpi, imageType);
}
```

Saving TIFF file:

```
private void saveImage(String absoluteFilename, BufferedImage[] images) 
        throws IOException, Exception {
    if(images == null || images.length <= 0) {          
        return;
    }

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    RandomAccessOutputStream rout = new FileCacheRandomAccessOutputStream(baos);        

    ImageParam[] imageParams = new ImageParam[images.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
        imageParams[i] = imageTool.getTiffBuilder(DPI).build();
    }

    TIFFTweaker.writeMultipageTIFF(rout, imageParams, images);

    byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();

    if (byteArray != null && byteArray.length > 0) {
        fileToolManager.getFileTool().save(byteArray, absoluteFilename);
    }

    baos.close();
}
```

Comment: Probably a font used in that pdf you have available on your local machine is not present on the RHEL machine.

Comment: 1) current version is 2.0.9 2) are there any log messages? 3) is the Zapf Dingbats font installed? Or MS-Gothic?

Comment: Please answer the question yourself, or delete the question.